# How to change annotation value at runtime using reflection?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

Below is the annotation.

```
@Before(value="execution(* class.method(**)")
```

Can i change the value of single value annotation using java reflection?

Please suggest.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062110/modifying-annotation-attribute-value-at-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 4):

The description of what you are looking for can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276270/1713801). But be wary about using such approach, some of the caveats of it are also described.

Also, the retention policy of the annotation has to be **runtime**, for this.

The link in the comment to your question leads to a post that *looks* like something you are asking about, but the difference is that it is about a JPA/Hibernate annotation where in the run-time you get a *proxy* class to your class.