# How to change the name of @XmlElement dynamically?

Tags: java, xml, annotations

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")

public class DynamicHead {

@XmlElement(name="head")
public Head head;

@XmlElement(name="body")
public DynamicBody body;

public DynamicHead() {}
}
```

Hi, I have simple question. I just wanna change the name property of @XmlElement from java code dynamically. How can I do this?

I found this code in XmlElement source,

```
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({FIELD, METHOD})
public @interface XmlElement {
    /**
     * Name of the XML Schema element.
     * <p> If the value is "##default", then element name is derived from the
     * JavaBean property name. 
     */
    String name() default "##default";
```

Which means, it works on run-time, so isn't it possible to change that value dynamically?

It doesn't matter whether I do coding in this class file or another class file that I use this class. Please help me guys!! :)

Comment: does your mapper is configured to accept more than one type of XMLs...

Comment: You can see how to change annotation value at runtime here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14276270/1713801, though it is very questionable whether you *should* use such approach.