# how to modify an attribute of an annotation at runtime

Tags: java, annotations

i have two annotations located in a file like this:

```
**file package-info.java**

@CallService(name ="My first kurento app")
@SipApplication(name = "default-name-sip-app", description = "default description of the   SipApplication", displayName = "default-displayName")
package com.kurento.kmf.sip;

import javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipApplication;
import com.kurento.kmf.sip.annotation.CallService;
```

I need that the value of name attribute from CallService goes to name attribute of @SipApplication in runtime.

I have some code inspired from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime) and it looks like the value of the attribute has changed, but it doesnt work. The code is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/y0Gq2DZK). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Annotations are designed to associate static metadata to classes as [Oracle says here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).

Anyway, if you still want to associate this variable metadata to an annotation, you could achieve this associating a custom class to both annotations that is holding the value you want to be variable.

**[Working example here](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-tests/blob/517e91d06435ec91ce093fa061d149e3f731e4c4/src/test/java/org/andresoviedo/tests/annotations/AnnotationsTest.java):**

```
// annotate your class with you custom class
@CallService(name=MyVariableMetadata.class)
```

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for the response, but your nice code does not solve my problem, and i think i cannot resolve it. I need to change the value of a third party anotation tag with the value of my custom anotation at runtime before the value of the third party anotation is procesed. Thanks anyway

Comment: And what about using Aspects or Instrumenting your third party class?

Comment: finally, we have discover that we can use a Mbean exposed by JMX in order to resolve this problem.