# Using custom timeout in Spring transaction management

Tags: java, spring-transactions, properties-file, transactionmanager

I have several methods with spring `@Transactional` in my project as following:

```
@Transactional(value = "sys.tx.mngr", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addMember(InputParam input) 
{
       // do somthing...
}

@Transactional(value = "sys.tx.mngr", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void blockMember(InputBlockParam param) 
{
      // do somthing...
}
```

Then I set different timeout per method as following:

```
@Transactional(value = "sys.tx.mngr", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,timeout = 40)
public void addMember(InputParam input) 
{
       // do somthing...
}

@Transactional(value = "sys.tx.mngr", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout = 20)
public void blockMember(InputBlockParam param) 
{
     // do somthing...
}
```

I want in last step set timeout as configurable by a properties file but I don't know what.
Is there any solution for set timeout in `spring Transactional` annotaion configurable or dynamically?

**EDIT:**
I define `sys.tx.mngr` in spring context file as following:

```
<bean id="sys.tx.mngr" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="sys.tx.mngr" />
```

Or is there alternative way for define timeout in  spring context file per method?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done on following ways only :-

```
a) Using Reflection.
b) Using Instrumentation.
c) Using TransactionTemplate (Programatically transaction).
```

For (a) & (b) you can have your class like following :-

```
public class Test implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
System.out.println("Sample prop 1 value : "+env.resolvePlaceholders("${prop1.value}"));
//Code to set/modify Transactional annotation "timeout" 
// attribute values for all methods
}

}
```

Link on how to set/modify values can be found here

[Modify field annotation value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367384/modify-field-annotation-value-dynamically) 
[Modify a class definition's annotation string parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime/14276270#14276270)

For (c) you can have config like :-

```
public class MemberDaoImpl {

@Autowired
private Environment env;
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

        public void addMember(InputParam input) {  
  transactionTemplate.setTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.resolvePlaceholders("${addmember.timeout}")));
               // do somthing...
        }

}

<bean id="memberDao" class="com.xxx.impl.MemberDaoImpl">
    <property name="transactionTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="sys.tx.mngr" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sys.tx.mngr" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank. Isn't there exist simple solution? I edited my question.

Comment: Define your own transaction manager, override these determineTimeout(..), use a threadlocal that sets the timeout based on a custom annotation, or AOP, several ways to achieve it.