# Compile-time dynamic annotation parameters

Tags: java, jpa

I know you can't change annotation parameters dynamically at run-time. I know the value at compile-time but not within the scope of the annotated type. I also have no controll over the annotation itself.

I want to use this for JPA, so I'll use it in the example as well:

I have a *base program* defining an entity `A`:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=JOINED) //default strategy
public class A { }
```

Now I have a *flavor* built on top of that program, i.e. it uses the *base program* like a library but both are compiled together. The *flavor* extends `A` and it should be able to determine its inheritance strategy, i.e. override the parameter value of `@Inhertitance` of type `A`.

Is there a way to accomplish this without messing with the byte code?

Comment: You can't "override" inheritance in a subclass. You likely could in orm.xml specifying inheritance for the base class.

Comment: Unlike with Spring I never got in touch with XML configuration for JPA, this could very well solve my specific problem, thanks for the hint! I'm still interested in a general approach to this, though.

Comment: Also to make it clear, I don't want to "override" the annotation in the subclass, I know that's not how it works. It just has to be done within the *flavor*.

Comment: I know. Thus, in the *flavor* I need to change the inheritance type of the root class, that's the whole point of this question...

Comment: There is no "official" way to change an annotation during runtime. Nevertheless there is a question that shows how to do that with reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367384/modify-field-annotation-value-dynamically. But remember that this is highly JDK specific and may break for different environments or versions.