# How to dynamically set value of mask option of @Validate annotation

Tags: java, regex, spring, annotations

Here's the code:

SomeFile.properties

```
string.regex="someRegex"
```

SomeActionClass.java

```
@Value("${string.regex}")
private String REGEX="";

@Validate(mask = REGEX)
private String stringToValidate;
```

The file SomeFile.properties is loaded on server startup and the value "someRegex" is stored somewhere in the session, so it is available.

The problem is that mask requires a constant value, and if I put final at REGEX="" I cannot overwrite the init value with the string.regex one; on the other hand if I put final but do not initialize the variable, java compiler complain about it.

Is there a way to use mask option with a value retrieved from file that I do not know?

Is it possible to do this directly on a jsp in a smart way, since I've have several fields to validate and I do not want to perform a check and write a message error for each one?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation value can be changed at runtime using reflection.

Please take a look at this (see the post marked as answer)

[Modify a class definition's annotation string parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

Be careful with this approach, some of the caveats of it are also described. Also, for being able to chenge this value at runtime, the **retention policy** for the annotation has to be `Runtime`

It's not the solution to your particular question, but it has useful information on how ti perform this operation on annotations.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.I suppose I've to find another way to validate  the form fields in my jsp.