# JUnit and Contiperf: Properties file to dynamically create contiperf annotation values

Tags: java, junit, properties, annotations, contiperf

I am currently in the middle of some performance testing using contiperf, annotation based performance testing, with JUnit.

I am loading JUnit tests from a properties file and wanted to be able to also load annotations values from these properties file.

I have searched online and cannot find a way to dynamically create annotation values for Contiperf. If anyone knows how to do this, can they point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check out [this link](https://github.com/lucaspouzac/contiperf/blob/master/src/main/java/org/databene/contiperf/junit/ContiPerfRule.java) and understand how contiperf works internally:

It is essentially a JUnit rule that creates its own threadpool based on the extracted annotation values, with each test invocation running on a single thread. It reads these annotation values from the FramworkMethod reference in the apply method.

A hack to go around this is to understand [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

Then you change the contiperf rule itself by creating a constructor to the rule taking in your "property values", updating the annotation values of the "Framework method" before it is passed into the PerfTestStatement().

I hope this small workaround is what you were looking for!