# How mock jcabi annotation parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jcabi

I have some code like below.

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = Constant.RETRY_ATTEMPTS, delay = Constant.RETRY_DELAY, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void method() {
    // some processing
    //throw exception if HTTP operation is not successful. (use of retry)
}
```

The value of ***RETRY_ATTEMPTS*** and ***RETRY_DELAY*** variable come from a separate *Constant* class, which are int primitive. Both the variable are defined as *public static final*.

How can I override these values while writing the unit testcases. The actual values increases running time of unit testcases.

I have already tried two approach: Both did not work

> 1. Using PowerMock with Whitebox.setInternalState().
> 2. Using Reflection as well.

---

**Edit:**
As mentioned by @yegor256, that it is not possible, I would like to know, why it is not possible? When these annotations get loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change them in runtime. What you should do, in order to make your `method()` testable is to create a separate "decorator" class:

```
interface Foo {
  void method();
}
class FooWithRetry implements Foo {
  private final Foo origin;
  @Override
  @RetryOnFailure(attempts = Constant.RETRY_ATTEMPTS)
  public void method() {
    this.origin.method();
  }
}
```

Then, for test purposes, use another implementation of `Foo`:

```
class FooWithUnlimitedRetry implements Foo {
  private final Foo origin;
  @Override
  @RetryOnFailure(attempts = 10000)
  public void method() {
    this.origin.method();
  }
}
```

That's the best you can do. Unfortunately.

Comment: At the moment instead of annotations, I implemented my own class for doing the retries. I will try this approach for sure.

Comment: I have a further question, why it is not possible to overwrite these annotations?

Comment: Yes. That I understood previously. I meant what is so different about annotations that they can't be overridden, even through mocking frameworks and java reflections.

Comment: You can, actually, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime/14276270