# Change annotation value of field annotation in Java 8

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8

I think title describes the problem. Here's some code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        assertEquals("foo", Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(Anno.class).param());

        // the magic here -> set to bar

        assertEquals("bar", Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(Anno.class).param());
    }

    @Anno(param = "foo")
    public void myMethod() {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Anno {
        String param();
    }
}
```

So far I'm guessing this is not possible. It seems that always when you try to get a method via reflection you only get copies and all values (like annotations) are reread from a deeper java layer. In these copies you could change values but these are gone if you reload.

Is there something I missed or is it really not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime

Comment: @Flown, an accepted answer in that question does not work in Java-8. It's possible to solve this, but of course the solution would be very dirty and fragile. I guess, it's much better to give up and move to solve the *original* problem instead.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are *modifiers* just like `private` or `synchronized`. They are part of the invariant static structure of a class and not intended to be modified. You can hack into the Reflection implementation to make a particular method print what you want, but besides the dirtiness of the hack, you simply haven’t changed the annotation, you just hacked a data structure of a particular library.

There are other Reflection or byte code manipulation libraries which won’t use the built-in Reflection API but read the byte code directly (e.g. via `getResource()` or via the Instrumentation API). These libraries will never notice your manipulation.

Note further, since these values are supposed to be constants embedded in the class file, a Reflection implementation could always use lazy fetching *plus* dropping of the cached values depending on uncontrollable conditions as these values can always be refetched. There’s also no guaranty that the Reflection implementation uses data structures at all; it could also generate code returning the constant values.

In other words, if you want to associate mutable data with a method, don’t use annotations. You could simple use a `Map<Method,MutableData>`, or, if you just have that one particular method, declare a good old `static` field which already provides all the features you need and is much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a link to do the same task before Java 8. It seems to be possible to do the same in Java 8 (1.8.0_51). The whole test setup

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.check();
        Test.change();
        t.check();
        new Test().check();
    }

    public Test() {

    }

    public static void change() {
        try {
            Method m = Test.class.getMethod("myMethod");
            // The map has to be built for the first time
            m.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            Class<?> superclass = m.getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field declaredField = superclass.getDeclaredField("declaredAnnotations");
            declaredField.setAccessible(true);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> map = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) declaredField
                    .get(m);
            map.put(Anno.class, new Anno() {

                @Override
                public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                    return Anno.class;
                }

                @Override
                public String param() {
                    return "new";
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException
                | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void check() {
        try {
            System.out.println(getClass().getMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(Anno.class).param());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Anno(param = "test")
    public void myMethod() {
    }

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Anno {
    String param();
}
```

Comment: That's fine, but OPs code contains not `m.getAnnotation(Anno.class)`, but `getClass().getMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(Anno.class)` which does not work with your answer. The `getClass().getMethod("myMethod")` always returns a fresh copy of internal `Method`, which is located in the array field of soft-referenced private class. So you will need much more reflection and keep the strong-reference somewhere to ensure the soft-ref is not expired.

Comment: Have you tried the code? It seems to work if you append `System.out.println(getClass().getMethod("myMethod").getAnnotation(Anno.class).param());` after the last System.out::println.

Comment: I tried on 1.8.0_25. It works in 1.8.0_40, but does not work on 1.8.0_25.

Comment: I tested it on 1.8.0_51

Comment: To sum up this attempt i have to quote your first comment: "It's dirty and fragile".

Comment: I wouldn’t call this a solution given the question’s wording. The question was about changing the annotation, but this hack only changes what certain Reflection code (of a certain implementation) will report. You could achieve the same by manipulating the `PrintStream` to show what you want to see, but I assume that then everyone would agree that this is not a solution. But the principle is the same…