# Ormlite: How change autorefresh annotation value programmatically?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite plugin on Android to manage my database, I set a class field with foreignAutoRefresh on true because this is the default behavior (normally I wanna to get all the Objects loaded automatically).

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "MyClass")
public class MyClass {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "field",
                   foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true )
    private MyObject field;

    ...
}
```

But in a specific rare situation I wanna to load a instance of MyClass without load automatically the Object field (setting the foreignAutoRefresh to false temporally)

How I can do that?

```
public class DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(...) {

        // ... here I want to set MyClass.field.autoreRefresh to false.

        List<MyClass> myClass = myClassDao.queryForAll();

        ... do some of work here ...

        // ... set again the autoRefresh field value to true.
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way of changing java annotations on-the-fly. Go and see how to do this at: 
[Modify a class definition's annotation string parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)