# Assign String in @Scheduled(cron ="Some String")

Tags: java, spring, scheduler, spring-scheduled

We have a properties file in which we mention to take the properties to be taken from JSON/Zookeeper.

Example:

```
AppName : SampleApp
```

Inside SampleApp.properties we will specify

```
configmode=json
jsonfile=/config.json
```

There are many examples how to assign the properties inside the @Scheduled annotation using properties file.

But in this scenario ,

we have to read the property using some Java class (say Name is `Config`) `String cronExp=Config.get("CRONEXPRESSION") ;`
and put that cron inside `@Scheduled(cron = cronExp)` ..Is this possible?

Note we cannot move the CRONEXPRESSION propepty to property file directly..Inside properties file we mention json..inside code we read that json and pick the property from there..

Comment: Check this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/75408-feature-scheduled-with-value-cron-expression

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*

saddly, you cannot do that.

In Java, annotation attributes are resolved at compile time. Which means that you can only provide an immediate value or a constant.

*Use case specific answer:*

Spring let's you use [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in a number of places. In this case, the value of the annotation's attribute is still resolved at compile time, but this value is evaluated by Spring at runtime. @RC provided a [good link to a discussion of the details](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/75408-feature-scheduled-with-value-cron-expression).

*Somewhat longer answer:*

It is possible to [modify annotations at runtime by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime), but that's a tricky path, and the code processing the annotation need to handle the case where annotations change at runtime (this is very rarely the case).