# Gson : serilize object witout considering value in @SerializedName annotation

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a class having following structure

```
public class Model {

    @SerializedName("1")
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

I need to serialize this class using gson so that i will get a output like

```
{"name":"Lorem Ipsum"}
```

instead of

```
{"1":"Lorem Ipsum"}
```

I know that removing @SerializedName("1") will solve my problem. But due to some reasons I cannot change or add anything in the Model class.

So is there any way to do that without removing the  @SerializedName Annotation ? I am usig Gson 2.3.1

Comment: Perhaps you can change the value of the annotation at runtime? Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime

Comment: @kevto Yeah we can change the annotation, but the model is actually too complex.