# Can I add/change a java annotation with code?

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations

So I am using the @Document(collection="xxxxx") mongodb annotation for some pojo classes I have. I am wanting to be able to change "collection=xxxxx" to something like "collection=test_xxxxxx" only when I am running my integration tests so that I can distinguish these collections easily from my documents I generate in my Test environment on my server.

Is there a way to update these with Java code?

Comment: [modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

The article is quite old, but perhaps it helps you:
http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html