# How to inject a value from application.properties into @PayloadRoot namespace-value

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, spring-ws

in my project it's necessary to inject a value from the *application.properties* file, profile-dependent, into the endpoint-class to the namespace-variable of the *@PayloadRoot* annotation.

**The problem:** the namespace-value must be a constant and in spring I can't inject a value into a final variable.
I find an advice to inject in this way:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "${my.namespace}", localPart = "getMyRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<MyResult> myMethod(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MyInput> request) {
```

but ... it doesn't work.
Has anyone a working solution?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of the following:

1) Use reflection once you have the appropriate value (but you need to make sure that you set the value before the endpoint mapping occurs): [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

2) Extends the class [PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.html) and in the method getLookupKeysForMethod, use a custom a method **getQNameFromAnnotation** where you will inject the correct value of the namespace.

```
private QName getQNameFromAnnotation(PayloadRoot payloadRoot) {
    return new QName(/*INJECT YOURNAMESPACE HERE*/, payloadRoot.localPart());
}
```

Comment: Hi VirtualTroll,
thanks for your qualified answer.
My problem was, that I had three server (devel, test, prod) running with my webservice. each different webservice needs a own wsdl with an individual address-location (that points to the right server). thats the essential fact. the namespace in the wsdl-file can be the same in the three wsdl-files. and so there's no need for a profile-related namespace value in the PayloadRoot-annotation.
That solved my problem. but good to know, there's a another solution if it must be profile-dependent.