# is there a way of handling this Attribute value must be constant error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to invoke this method:

```
public Response getWithPathParam(@ApiParam( 
        value = "Service group to check",
        allowableValues = ApiConstants.components,                                                   
        required = true )
```

but want that allowableValues attribute will get a value that can be varying.

what I mean that I assuming allowableValues is a String.

I wondering if there is a way of reading a string from configuration and pass it into the attributes.

my attempt so far just led into the error of:

"Attribute value must be constant"

can you help please?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you don't provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: Are you trying to assign value to final field .Can you please provide your code.

Comment: "this method"? Where is the method? The attribute `allowableValues` is an attribute of *what*? What context of the word "attribute" are you referring to? In short, your question is very, very unclear.

Comment: He probably means "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression” error.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, compiler errors cannot be handled in any way other than fixing them.
It is only runtime errors that can somehow be handled.

According to the java language specification, a parameter to an annotation must be a *compile-time constant*.

This means that you cannot do anything even remotely close to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Java prevents to accept any other annotation parameter other than a constant, so you need to change `ApiConstants.components` to be a fixed value, for example:

```
  class ApiConstants{
     public static final String[] CONSTANTS = {"VAL_1","VAL_2"};
  }
```

If you still want to stay with dynamic configuration, then you need to handle it within the method itself.

Comment: but if the method is a 3rd party.

Comment: there is no way to inject it?

Comment: Only aspect programming,  but if you will go that way,,  it means your design is wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime