# Change the return type of annotation method

Tags: java, annotations

given the following custom annotation

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
 public @interface TGT {
  String age();
}
```

and somewhere in a class code it is used for a field as :

```
  @TGT(age="someValue")
  private String someID;
```

Is it possible to change the return value of someID's method age() from "someValue": to so something else or in other words other String value?So when someone gets someID's annotation via reflection and then invokes the age() method of the annotation to get different value?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is bit confusing. What should change what based on what? Maybe post some example after that changes.

Comment: Basicly my question is once we set annotation with values mapped to the parameters ,can we ever change these values via reflection ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Modify a class definition's annotation string parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268981)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm completely misunderstanding you...or if you're not quite understanding annotations.  `age()` is the annotation value attached.  It's set in stone at compile-time (unless you do something truly evil with reflection and bytecode manipulation).  A field annotated with this annotation with a different value will naturally have a different value.  What is it that you're *really* trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but not with pure reflection. If you want to change the object without replacing it by another object you'll have to use a bytecode manipulation lib like ASM (see how it is done in [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)). But this way would be very complex.

In case if you are allowed to replace an abject by a proxy it would even be possible with pure reflection + aspects engine (se how [Spring does it with help of CGLIB](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s06.html)).