# Java - How to edit annotation fields at runtime?

Tags: java, annotations

I wrote this simple annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface CSVColumn {
    String name();

    int order();
}
```

which I'm currently using to annotate some getter methods of a class.
I'm able to get the values of this annotation at runtime:

```
    Class classType = objects[0].getClass();
    Method[] methodsArray = classType.getDeclaredMethods();
    List<Method> methods = Arrays.asList(methodsArray);
    //FIlter annotated methods
    methods = methods.stream().filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(CSVColumn.class) != null).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Iterator<Method> methodIterator = methods.iterator();

    while (methodIterator.hasNext()) {
        Method method = methodIterator.next();
        CSVColumn csvColumn = method.getAnnotation(CSVColumn.class);
        String header = csvColumn.name();
    }
```

but how could I set the field **name** of the annotation to another value?
Should/could I declare some setter methods in the annotation class?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime

Comment: Even though it may be possible to change annotations at runtime by digging in the JVM internals, you're really not supposed to do that. You need to come up with a different data structure for storing the information you need to change at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the utility class [`AnnotationUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/AnnotationUtil.java)

You can do `changeAnnotation(csvColumn, "name", "newName")`

Comment: Thanks man, I will have a lot to learn from your repo. It's an awesome work, congratulations.