# Making class literal some kind of 'configurable'

Tags: java, maven, reflection

Imagine to have this class in some library, which gets added to another project as maven dependency:

```
class A {

    // What can I do to replace B.class ?
    @SomeAnnotation(B.class)
    private String someValue;

}
```

I would like to make the class literal B.class some kind of configurable for the mvn project that uses this as dependency. Do I need to do it via reflection capabilities, what are my possibilities here?

Comment: I guess you cannot, even with reflections. Annotations are declarative

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime

Comment: Where do you want to configure the value?

Comment: @ernest_k somewhere in the project that uses the containing dependency, that´s where I know which class literal would replace B.class

Comment: @Jasper perhaps you could go up level and explain what problem you are trying to achieve there may be an alternative solution.