# Imposing a static variable in all subclasses of an interface

Tags: java, interface, static

I have an interface `Calculator` which shapes a class that computes some results and returns them with a given schema.

```
interface Calculator {
    List<Object> getResults();
    List<String> schema();
}
```

Each of its subclasses has a different schema, as they do not compute exactly the same things. But all instances of a same subclass have the same schema since it computes the same way everytime.

The problem is that I want to access that schema somewhere else in my code without having to compute anything, as computations can be expensive.

Ideally, I would like that each subclass have its own `public static final List<String> SCHEMA` attribute. But since static attributes/methods cannot be overriden, I cannot require that all subclasses of the `Calculator` interface implement it.

Is there a way around, or must I store the schema when I compute the results, and pass this schema around for later use? (this can become tedious I guess)

Comment: You cant force a class to define a static field. Do you really need that or can just go with Subclass.SCHEMA and not forget to define it for each subclass?

Comment: I can go for the second option, but does that mean that another programmer can subclass the interface and forget about SCHEMA?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll do that, since one need to instanciate a subclass to access the SCHEMA, it should not be that much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For string constants you could use a runtime **class annotation** for the schema,
and a runtime check:

```
default List<String> schema() {
    Schema schema = getClass().getAnnotation(Schema.class);
    if (schema == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Class is missing @Schema annotation: "
            + getClass().getName());
    }
    return schema.getValues();
}

@Schema({"e", "pi", "i"})
public class ScientificCalculator implements Calculator { ... }
```

More dynamic things could be done with overriding `schema()`.

Comment: Seems to be a quite smart solution, but my first thought is : what if someone can modify it and thus it is not static & final? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

Comment: If yes I'll use tsolakp's solution since I do not want to complicate my code too much, and my class design has some flaws anyway, I may change it. But class annotation seems to be a very interesting solution, I'll dig more into it.