# Pass dynamic parameters to an annotation in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a custom annotation which is declared as below and have some implementation for this.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SampleTestCase {
    public int caseID() default -1;
    public int suiteId() default -1;
}
```

Now, I am trying to use this annotation and trying to send runtime parameters to it.

```
ConfigHelper config = new ConfigHelper();
int caseId = config.getTestCaseID();

@SampleTestCase(caseID=caseId,suiteId="Test")
public void testCaseOne(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

Getting an error as "The value for annotation attribute TivoTestCase.caseID must be a constant expression".

Is there any way to pass dynamic parameters to an annotation other than this way??

Comment: no. An annotation requires a constant. It would be difficult to bind a not-yet-decided value on compile-time

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime