# changing custom annotations on the fly from Spring Cloud Config Server. Is it possible?

Tags: spring-boot, reflection, annotations, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

Context: I need to provide a way to change parameter values during production on lower performance cost as possible.

Goal: I want change annotation values on fly and apply it at once on all microservices instances.

Personal background and limitations: I know I can use Spring Cloud Config to change parameters on the fly like explained in [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)  and I Know there is some challenges and pitfalls involved on changing annotations on the fly also like discussed in [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968373/4148175).

I know that Spring Cloud Config can be used for setting up a centralized configuration applied to all microservice instances during boot/start. I have used it a bit. I am wondering if I can use it for centralizing parameters that can affect customized annotations on fly.

An imagined solution is:

... whenever I need somepRopertyValue

```
@Value("${config.somePropertyValue}")
private String somePropertyValue;

@Bean
public String somePropertyValue(){
    return somePropertyValue;
}
```

A config client in all microservices endpoint that must be call not only when the application start but whenever somePropertyValue managed in Spring Cloud Config Server bootstrap.properties is updated:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringConfigClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RefreshScope
@RestController
class MessageRestController {

    @Value("${server.somePropertyValue:Unable to connect to config server}")
    private String somePropertyValue;

    @RequestMapping("/server/somePropertyValue")
    String getSomePropertyValue() {
        return this.somePropertyValue;
    }
}
```

And somehow somePropertyValue is maintened in Spring Cloud Config and if change during production time it  affects on demand everywhere somePropertyValue is annoted in all microservice instances.

I am currently reaching this behaviour by adding a kafka consumer in all SpringBoot microservices that listen/observe a topic and when it receives a new messagge it changes on the fly the parameter value. It seems so odd that I created a Kafka dependency in all company microservices. Since I have used Spring Config for a bit similar scenario I am wondering if there is a better alternative using some out-of-box Spring approach. Also performance is highly important in my case and a bit delay on syncronize all parameters isn't an issue. By delay I mean that two or three seconds to update parameters in all microservices isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two ways to do that:**

**i-** There's a refresh endpoint, and you can actually call that for a service, and it'll actually refresh its configurations without restarting itself, which is pretty neat. e.g. **MS-A** is listing on `8080` then do a `POST` request at this endpoint:
`localhost:8080/refresh`.

*NOTE:* **Spring Actuator** actually adds a RefreshEndpoint to the app automatically when we annotate a controller in MS-A with `@RefreshScope`.

**ii-** What you can also do is use [Spring Cloud Bus](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/html/), and broadcast an event, and then every service **listens on** that and refreshes itself. That's handy if you have dozens of services all using the **Config Server**, and you don't want to go one by one and hit a `/refresh` endpoint as we have did in 1st approach. You just want to broadcast a message to a bus and have all these things automatically pick it up.

**Reference:** Both concepts I've learnt while taking course at [Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/java-microservices-spring-cloud-developing-services/)