# Java LocalDate & Gson serializer - InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to make a JSon-String from a class that contains a LocalDate field, but I always get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @197ac685
```

I already searched for this and apparently I should register a custom adapter, which I did:

```
public class GsonLocalDateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");


@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
                             final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString(), formatter);
}

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.format(formatter));
}
}

var gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new GsonLocalDateAdapter())
            .create();
    var json = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

It doesn't even hit the breakpoint in the serialize method.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Java and what version of Gson? Also, why are you registering `LocalDateTime.class` if `LocalDate.class` is what you want to serialize?

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I'm trying to make a JSon-String from a class that contains a LocalDate field, but I always get this error: ..."*

Use *LocalDate* instead of *LocalDateTime*, for the *registerTypeAdapter* method.

```java
registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new GsonLocalDateAdapter())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post on stack overflow and related discussions there:
[java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872389/java-lang-reflect-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-field-private-fina/73872814#73872814)

In your case, you would fix this problem by adding:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.