# Modify a method annotation parameter at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, methods, annotations

I found this thread: [How to change annotation value at runtime using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274234/how-to-change-annotation-value-at-runtime-using-reflection)

And I'm trying to change method annotation, but java.lang.reflect.Method does not contain any map-field like "annotations" or method like "getDeclaredAnnotationMap"

There is only `private byte[] annotations` but what can I do with this byte array?

So, how to modify annotation of method?

EDIT:
I created that: http://pastebin.com/T2rewcwU 
But that only edit this instance of method, if you uncomment 33 line of code then value will reset.

Comment: Are you sure? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations--

Comment: "map-field", and "getDeclaredAnnotation**Map**", that only copied array with annotations, nothing will change if you edit it.

Comment: Oops, too late for me. I stopped reading after the JavaDocs "The caller of this method is free to modify the returned array".

Comment: ok, I created that: http://pastebin.com/T2rewcwU , but this only edit current instance of Method class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a class `AnnotationUtil` to resolve the seris requirements.

It can add/remove/change annotation value on class/field/method instance.

Note that use `ReflectUtil` to get root field/method when add/remove annotation.

See it on github:

[AnnotationUtil](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/cn/xdean/jex/reflect/AnnotationUtil.java)

[ReflectUtil](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/cn/xdean/jex/reflect/ReflectUtil.java)

Comment: I don't even remember why I needed this now, and I already know that trick (as I was only missing that root instance) but forgot about this question.
Note that it will not work in next java versions, as they don't allow anymore for reflection between modules - additional jvm arguments will need to be used - or agent+instrumentation/unsafe/native code.
I will accept this answer tho.

Comment: @GotoFinal …and in case of class annotations, they’re held by a `SoftReference`, which allows garbage collecting the cached data and effectively revert your manipulations.

Comment: this is truly a last resort, but i learned a lot going through your utils :)

Comment: Links are broken :(

Comment: @PaulPraet Link is back. Enjoy!  :)

Comment: @DeanXu can you kindly please provide working example for using addAnnotation method for class methods, specifically the Annotation type parameter passed into the method

Comment: @JayD https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/test/java/cn/xdean/jex/reflect/AnnotationUtilTest.java

Comment: @DeanXu cheers man, guess I didn't looked close enough