# JPA - Select All Rows from Dynamic Table Name

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

Hi guys I am new to jpa, named queries, etc.. and I need something like this:

```
select t from :tableName t
```

Later in code I want something like this:

```
em.createQuery(...);
setParameter("tableName", "Person")
```

Result would be:

```
select * from person
```

How to write such a generic jpa query statement allowing to select all rows from :tableName which may be defined at runtime? thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: How do I specify the table name corresponding to a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906671/jpa-how-do-i-specify-the-table-name-corresponding-to-a-class-at-runtime)

Comment: hi, there are no queries in that question

Comment: It can't be done this way, table name can't be parametrized.

Comment: JDBC doesnt, in general, allow use of a parameter to set the table name ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think this works well

```
 EntityManagerFactory emfactory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Eclipselink_JPA" );
  EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();

  Query query = entitymanager.
  createQuery("Select p from Person p");
  List<String> list = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: not working.. i am using hibernate and sql server. see error: SQLServerException: Must declare the table variable

Answer (score 1):

`setParameter("foo", foo)` is used to set the value for column of the table not to set the table name. I do not think it will work, as you want to set the table name dynamically.

You can try this:

```
public returnType foo(String tableName){
    String jpql = "SELECT t FROM " + tableName+ " t";
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
    //rest of the code    
}
```

Comment: Why would he try that? There is no such thing as `SELECT *` in JPQL.